# PHP md5_file hash is not the same as other online hash generators

Tags: php, hash, md5, md5-file

I am uploading a file using PHP which uses md5_hash to create a MD5 hash of the file.

When I upload that same file to other online MD5 hash generators they return something else.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
$MD5 = md5_file($_FILES['inputname']['tmp_name']);
var_dump($MD5);

string(32) "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
```

https://md5file.com/calculator says:

```
MD5 3be70563560066c0751a8e9427949bbf
```

Comment: Have you tried `$MD5 = md5($_FILES['inputname']['tmp_name']);`?

Comment: Yes, this gives another hash. If I just use md5() without getting the file contents I am simply hashing the temp filename.

Comment: Maybe the other online hash generators are resampling the file (scanning for viruses, etc.), hard to say why it does that.

Comment: I thought that too, but I tested 3 different hashers and they come up with the same hash.

Comment: Maybe that online calculator uses `md5` instead of what you're using `md5_file` and uses different algos. That's all I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` is the MD5-hash of the empty string. This means that the file that the filename `$_FILES['inputname']['tmp_name']` points to is empty.

So, there is a major problem with the upload somewhere... maybe a server configuration error. It's impossible to say though, without further investigations.

Comment: You are correct. There was an issue with the PHP configuration which was clearing the cache before I could get to the posted file.